# HTTP POST request with JSON object as data

Tags: java, json, http, post

I am struggling to make an HTTP POST request with JSON object as data.

As you can see below, first I created an HTTP Post request.  Then I commented out part of it and attempted to modify it in order to add JSON related code.  One of the things that confused me was that despite seeing a number of tutorials using the import "org.json.simple.JSONObject" my IDE reads an error message and states "the import org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be resolved".

Any advice about how to make this code work would be much appreciated.

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

 public class HTTPPostRequestWithSocket {

    public void sendRequest(){

        try {

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("instructorName", "Smith");
            obj.put("courseName", "Biology 101");
            obj.put("studentName1", "John Doe");
            obj.put("studentNumber", new Integer(100));
            obj.put("assignment1", "Test 1");
            obj.put("gradeAssignment1", new Double("95.3"));

           /*
           //Note that this code was taken out in order to attempt to send
           //the information in the form of JSON.
           String params = URLEncoder.encode("param1", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
            params += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("param2", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");
             */

            String hostname = "nameofthewebsite.com";
            int port = 80;

            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
            Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);
            String path = "/nameofapp";

            // Send headers
            BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new     
            OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
            wr.write("POST "+path+" HTTP/1.0rn");
            wr.write("Content-Length: "+obj.length()+"rn");
            wr.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencodedrn");
            wr.write("rn");

            // Send parameters
            wr.write(obj);
            wr.flush();

            // Get response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
             String line;

            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                }

            wr.close();
            rd.close();
            socket.close();//Should this be closed at this point?
            }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
}
```

Comment: is the json-simple jar file in your CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your IDE says it cannot resolve the import `org.json.simple.JSONObject` is because the `org.json.simple.*` packages and classes are not included in Java, but rather belong to the [JSON Simple library](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).

Comment: Thank you.  I'll have to download and add the jar.

Comment: If you could accept this answer, that would help so others also know this question has been answered.
Thank you.

Comment: Okay.  I can do that.  I really appreciate you adding the link. But, I'm still going to repost the question, minus the "import org.json.simple.JSONObject" part, because I'm really struggling and am hoping that somebody can come along that is gracious/merciful enough to take a look at the code itself and help me to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I think that uses Socket is not a good idea. You can better use:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ (A HTTP Client)

or a java.net.URLConnection. Example:

http://crunchify.com/create-very-simple-jersey-rest-service-and-send-json-data-from-java-client/

Answer (score 0):

You need the jar with the org.json.simple.JSONObject implementation:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm

Comment: I've been struggling to look at information from different tutorials and synthesize  everything together correctly to try to make an HTTP POST request with JSON object as data. So, does the code itself make sense?